# Is there a Python function for counting the number of strings in a cell and reporting these in a new dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function, data-manipulation

Let's stay I have a grocery list with one column titled "Groceries". In each row there is a list of strings, for example.

| Groceries |
| --- |
| apples, bananas, oranges |
| apples, bananas, bananas, pears |
| oranges, pears, bananas |

Is there a way to count each string and add a "tally" is a new dataframe or similar thing with the appropriately labeled item? The dataframe would then look like:

| apples | oranges | bananas | pears |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |

I can't find a function that will recognize strings and count them in the appropriate row/column with the string name. I am also pretty new to Python and am not sure what would go into creating a function that would do this.

Comment: As with many requests, this would be easier to do in straight Python code BEFORE you shove the data into pandas.  Is the original data being read from file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [`split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) the string on commas, [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.explode.html) to multiple rows, [`get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) to transform to 0/1, and [`groupby.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) to aggregate:

```
out = (pd
 .get_dummies(df['Groceries'].str.split(',\s*').explode())
 .groupby(level=0).sum()
)
```

Or similar with [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
s = df['Groceries'].str.split(',\s*').explode()
out = pd.crosstab(s.index, s)
```

output:

```
   apples  bananas  oranges  pears
0       1        1        1      0
1       1        2        0      1
2       0        1        1      1
```